# QR Code Web Service

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am working on an mobile web app where people will be able to "check-in" (in a sense) by scanning a QR code at a location and it will direct to a certain URL and if the user is logged into the phone app then their attendance will be logged. The codes will be generated using a PHP library (different QR code / URL for every location).

My fear is that the user will see the URL in the browser when they scan the code and be able to enter it manually without scanning.

Anyone have any ideas to prevent this? This will be a mobile web app, and not a hybrid app in the market (read: no PhoneGap)

Comment: Some QR code scanning apps even have the option to not go to any URL encoded in a QR code directly, but showing the URL to the user first for them to check that it does not take them anywhere they might not want to go. // If your concept relies on URLs being kept a “secret”, then that’s a design error right there.

Comment: @livewire1407 Assuming the QR code eventually lands to a server hosting the web page for the business being checked into. Couldn't you use URL REWRITE in htaccess file on server to obscure the URL? Do the url's have to be SEO friendly or are they dedicated only to the APP functionality?

Comment: @CBroe I don't care if they see the url, I know there is no way to stop them of doing that. Since they will have a way of knowing the URL though, I am trying to find a way to prevent them from just typing that URL in every day to check in at the same location.

Comment: @Swodahs the URL does not need to be SEO friendly, and I plan to use url parameters. I am not very familiar with URL rewriting, how could I  determine if the user is actually scanning the code or typing a URL to allow it to only rewrite if they are scanning?

Answer (score 1):

I have been using PHP QR Code encoder by Dominik Dzienia.

http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/

Example:

```
include('qr/qrlib.php'); 

$text = 'my text';
QRcode::png($text);
echo $text;
```

Comment: I am using the same. My question is not in generaing the code, but rather in making users don't manually enter the URL the code generates, and thus "check-in" somewhere that they are not.

Comment: Maybe just set a cookie / session variable at some point before the QR Code is displayed. Then on the landing page where you are going to record the check-in, make sure it exists before recording the check-in. That way if they just have the URL it don't really do them any good unless they already have the cookie / session set. Then be sure to remove the cookie after a successful check in.

Comment: the user will be scanning a QR code in person at a location. the QR code will be linking to a website that links to the web app with URL parameters that indicate what location they are at. then the users session in the app will provide information about the user, and that data will be combined to record a "check-in" ... at least that how I have it planned now. That being said, I don't think the session thing will work because I don't know when they will be going to any particular location

Answer (score 0):

I guess one possibility would be some basic form of encryption.

create a hidden input containing some random string

```
  <?php
  $rnd=md5(rand());
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['rnd']=$rnd;
  ?>

  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $rnd; ?>">
```

md5 the hidden input with the qr code in javascript with http://www.myersdaily.org/joseph/javascript/md5-text.html and return the result along with the qr code.

then server side you can md5 the returned qr code with the same random string and check the result matches. If it does then you give the user a positive result.

since the random string changes every page load there is no way too cheat it

Answer (score -1):

Your situation as described might best be handled through an HTACCESS file as opposed to a PHP method. In using a HTACCESS file you can utilize MOD_REWRITE to eliminate the trailing information behind a URL such as session variables or other information (file name and extension - such as index.html) so that the browsed url will display as the parent path, for example:

http://www.yoursite.com/clients/abc123/index.html

would display as:

http://www.yoursite.com/clients/abc123/

or other ways depending on how your rewrite rule is set. I am by no means a expert on HTACCESS and the MOD_REWRITE rules, so i will recommend the following page and its related links at the bottom as a good place to start.

[guide to HTACCESS and MOD_REWRITE](http://www.branded3.com/blogs/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/)